# Remove data from RRDTool

Tags: rrdtool, rrd

I have several graphs created by RRDTool that collected bad data during a time period of a couple hours.

How can I remove the data from the RRD's during that time period so that it no longer displays?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Best method I found to do this...

1. Use [RRDTool Dump](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrddump.en.html) to export RRD files to XML.
2. Open the XML file, find and edit the bad data.
3. Restore the RRD file using [RRDTool Restore](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdrestore.en.html) .

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem where I wanted to discard the most recent few hours from my RRDtool databases, so I wrote a quick script to do it (apologies for the unconventional variable names - coding style inherited from work, sigh):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2                                                                                                                                                                                 
"""                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Modify XML data generated by `rrdtool dump` such that the last update was at                                                                                                                           
the unixtime specified (decimal). Data newer than this is simply omitted.                                                                                                                              

Sample usage::                                                                                                                                                                                         

    rrdtool dump foo.rrd \
       | python remove_samples_newer_than.py 1414782122 \
       | rrdtool restore - foo_trimmed.rrd                                                                                          
"""                                                                                                                                                                                                    

import sys                                                                                                                                                                                             

assert sys.argv[1:], "Must specify maximum Unix timestamp in decimal"                                                                                                                                  

iMaxUpdate = int(sys.argv[1])

for rLine in iter(sys.stdin.readline, ''):                                                                                                                                                             
    if "<lastupdate>" in rLine:                                                                                                                                                                        
        # <lastupdate>1414782122</lastupdate> <!-- 2014-10-31 19:02:02 GMT -->                                                                                                                         
        _, _, rData = rLine.partition("<lastupdate>")                                                                                                                                                  
        rData, _, _ = rData.partition("</lastupdate")                                                                                                                                                  
        iLastUpdate = int(rData)                                                                                                                                                                       
        assert iLastUpdate < iMaxUpdate, "Last update in RRD older than " \                                                                                                                            
                                    "the time you provided, nothing to do"                                                                                                                             
        print "<lastupdate>{0}</lastupdate>".format(iMaxUpdate)                                                                                                                                        
    elif "<row>" in rLine:                                                                                                                                                                             
        # <!-- 2014-10-17 20:04:00 BST / 1413572640 --> <row><v>9.8244774011e+01</v><v>8.5748587571e-01</v><v>4.2046610169e+00</v><v>9.3016101695e+01</v><v>5.0000000000e-02</v><v>1.6652542373e-01</  v><v>1.1757062147e+00</v><v>1.6901226735e+10</v><v>4.2023108608e+09</v><v>2.1457537707e+08</v><v>3.9597816832e+09</v><v>6.8812800000e+05</v><v>3.0433198080e+09</v><v>6.0198912250e+06</v><v>2.        0000000000e+00</v><v>0.0000000000e+00</v></row>                                                                                                                                                        
        rData, _, _ = rLine.partition("<row>")                                                                                                                                                         
        _, _, rData = rData.partition("/")                                                                                                                                                             
        rData, _, _ = rData.partition("--")                                                                                                                                                            
        rData = rData.strip()                                                                                                                                                                          
        iUpdate = int(rData)                                                                                                                                                                           
        if iUpdate < iMaxUpdate:                                                                                                                                                                       
            print rLine,                                                                                                                                                                               
    else:                                                                                                                                                                                              
        print rLine,
```

Worked for me. Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid writing and editing of xml file as this may takes few file IO calls(based on how much bad data you have) , you can also read entire rrd into memory using fetch and update values in-memory.

I did similar task using python + rrdtool and i ended up doing :

> 1. read rrd in-memory in a dictionary
> 2. fix values in the dictionary
> 3. delete existing rrd file
> 4. create new rrd with same name.

Comment: If you open sourced your solution, I bet you'd help out a lot of people!

Answer (score 0):

The only who proposed, what exactly to edit, was RobM. I tried his solution, and it did not work for me in rrdtool 1.4.7

My database uses AVERAGE, MAX and MIN. It contains DERIVE, GAUGE and COMPUTED. Intervals: second (70), minute (70), hour (25), day (367).
My task: delete some last part (typical reason: clock moved back).

I applied RobM's solution: change  to my new end time, delete all  after it. Restored database seemed to be normal. But it did not accept new additions.
I examined a newly created empty database. And I found in it 70 second records with NaN, same for minute and hour.

So, my working solution - if I delete  records in some period end, I add the same number of NaN records in this period beginning, with correctly decreasing times. Exception - daily records, they are only deleted without addition.
If period becomes empty after  deletes, I fill it with NaN records ending to my new end time (rounded to the period boundary).