# Updating values in an existing RRD file

Tags: rrdtool, rrd, cacti

I have an rrd file working fine under cacti, drawing a graph for me for more than a year from one data source.

Today, I discovered that the data in the rrd file is not correct. I have corrected the data source and fixed problem for the future. However, I need to divide the previous data by 2 to correct it historically as well.

Is it possible to update the values of an rrd file? If yes, how can I achieve this?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298484/remove-data-from-rrdtool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data in the RRAs cannot be directly changed once written.

However, what you can do is to dump the data to XML (using `rrdtool dump`); edit it using some other method; and then reload the data into a new RRD file (using `rrdtool restore`).  This, of course, requires you to create some method to automatically modify the values in the XML file, but this should be simpler than trying to modify the RRD directly.

Comment: thanks! it worked but it was really tricky as I had to modify some of the values based on the date but rrddump had the epoc timestamp. so I backed up the rrd file, dumped into an xml, ran a python script to modify the whole file, and restore. no issues, cacti is writing into new rrd file and graph looks good with new values. thanks again!!!